# JavaScript:User enters numbers until he enters 0.Each numbers parity is determined and at the end,the total number of even and odd numbers is printed

Tags: javascript, function

I also need to use the function to test the parity of the number. When I enter a few numbers (1,2,3,4 and then 0) the program shows "9 , 0 ". I'm not sure why

```
let Even = 0;
let Odd = 0;
let a = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number:"));
while (a != 0 ) {
        a = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number:"));
        isEven(a);
            if(true){
                Even = Even + a};
            if(false){
                Odd = Odd + a};
                };
console.log(Even,Odd);

function isEven(value){
    if (value%2 == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: If you want the total numbers you'd add 1 on each loop. Currently you are calculating the total sums.

Answer (score 0):

Two mistakes inside your loop:

```
isEven(a);
if(true){
    Even = Even + a
};
if(false){
    Odd = Odd + a
};
```

The first one is that you're calling `isEven` and not using the result. In the `if` you're literally just using `if(true)` and `if(false)`, so you will always go in the first one and never in the second.

The second mistake is that each time you're adding the entered number `a` instead of 1, which is what you want if you need the amount of even/odd numbers.

So, keeping your (rather unusual) structure, you would have:

```
var test = isEven(a);
if(test === true){
    Even = Even + 1;
}
if(test === false){
    Odd = Odd + 1;
}
```

In a more traditional way, I would suggest:

```
if(isEven(a)){
    Even = Even + 1;
} else {
    Odd = Odd + 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm a student and need to pass this class. It's kinda hard to understand and learn everything on online classes we have due to corona (hence the unusual structure). Anyways,thank you for clearing things up!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

You had some problems:
1.Suppose you type 1 the prompt will close and while first iteration will continue.
You open a new prompt so 1 will never be calculated.

```
let a = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number:"));
while (a != 0 ) {
        a = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number:"));
```

2. You check IsEven(a) but never give that value to your conditions.

l

```
et Even = 0;
    let Odd = 0;
    let a = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number:"));
    while (a != 0 ) {
           var isEvenResult = isEven(a)
                if(isEvenResult){
                    Even += parseInt(a);
                    }
               else{
                    Odd += parseInt(a);
                    }
        a = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number:"));
                    }`enter code here`
    console.log(Even +','+ Odd);
    function isEven(value){
        if (value%2 == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```